# Problema ao recuperar item clicado na ListActivity e devolvê-lo para activity anterior

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma Activity onde faço a chamada a uma outra Activity usando o `startActivityForResult`. 
Na Activity que foi chamada, tenho uma lista preenchida por produtos já cadastrados. 
Nessa lista, precisava de, ao clicar em algum dos produtos da lista, retornar o produto para a Activity anterior.

O problema é que: ao clicar no item da lista, não consigo recuperá-lo e devolvê-lo como resultado para a Activity anterior.

```
//Classe  CadPreVenda.Java 
     @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item){
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case ADICIONAR:
                Toast.makeText(CadPreVenda.this, "Clicou em ADD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG,"Log: Clicou em add");
                Intent i = new Intent(CadPreVenda.this, pvConsProduto.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                return true;

            case CANCELAR:
                Toast.makeText(CadPreVenda.this, "Clicou em CANCELAR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG,"Log: Clicou em CANCELAR");
                return true;

            case SALVAR:
                Toast.makeText(CadPreVenda.this, "Clicou em SALVAR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG,"Log: CLICOU EM SALVAR");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
//verifica se usuário confirmou a inclusão de algum item
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent it) {
    if(it == null){

        Context contexto = getApplicationContext();
        int duracao = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contexto, "Atenção! Produto não incluído!",duracao); 
        toast.show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Cancelou o processo.");
        Log.d(TAG, "Erro: Processo Abortado." );

    }
    else{
        Bundle params = it !=null ? it.getExtras(): null;
        if (params != null){
            String produto = params.getString("produto");
            Log.d(TAG, "Produto Add: "+produto);
        }
    }
```

Nessa classe, carrego a lista de produtos e tento devolver o retorno para a Activity anterior.

```
package br.sysandroid;

import java.util.List;

import br.sysandroid.dao.Lcm001DAO;
import br.sysandroid.dao.ProdutoAdapter;
import br.sysandroid.dao.banco.BancoDAO;
import br.sysandroid.model.LCM001;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class pvConsProduto extends ListActivity{
    Button btPesquisar, btSair;
    private Lcm001DAO ProdutoDAO;
    List<LCM001> produtos;
    ProdutoAdapter adapter;
    BancoDAO bancoDAO;

    public static final String TAG = "LOGVENDAS";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.consproduto);
        bancoDAO = new BancoDAO(this);

        //Código que não é relevante para o problema

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(list, v, position, id);

            try {
                Intent it = new Intent();
                it.putExtra("produto",produtos.get(position));                              
                Log.d(TAG, "Adicionando produto: "+produtos.get(position));   
                setResult(RESULT_OK,it);
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Algum erro aconteceu");
            } 
      }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        ProdutoDAO = new Lcm001DAO(this);
        ProdutoDAO.open();
        //Lê produtos do banco
        produtos = ProdutoDAO.lerProdutos();
        //seta produtos na lista
        ListView listaProduto = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        //ListView listaProduto = getListView();
        adapter = new ProdutoAdapter(this, produtos);
        listaProduto.setAdapter(adapter);
        super.onResume();

    }   
}
```

Ao clicar em algum dos itens da lista, no *Log* recebo isso:

```
10-31 09:08:47.002: D/LOGVENDAS(1663): Adicionando produto: br.sysandroid.model.LCM001@b2e9e0a8
10-31 09:08:47.212: D/GRAVANDOLOGS(1663): Produto Add: null
```

E gera esse *warn* no LogCat:

```
10-31 09:08:37.232: W/Bundle(1663): Key produto expected String but value was a br.sysandroid.model.LCM001.  The default value <null> was returned.
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663): java.lang.ClassCastException: br.sysandroid.model.LCM001 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1121)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at br.sysandroid.CadPreVenda.onActivityResult(CadPreVenda.java:107)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-31 09:08:37.322: W/Bundle(1663):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Verifique o seu código, especialmente onde a variável produto está retornando um valor null. Isso está causando o erro: 10-31 09:08:37.232: W/Bundle(1663): Key produto expected String but value was a br.sysandroid.model.LCM001.  The default value <null> was returned. A variavel espera um valor do tipo String e está retornando null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que está recuperando o valor da chave **"produto"** no `onActivityResult` (`CadPreVenda`), e atribuindo a um objeto do tipo `String`. Sendo que na `Activity` que fornece esse retorno (`pvConsProduto`), adicionou um `LCM001` como valor a **"produto"**.

Para funcionar altere a variável que recebe o valor do `Bundle` para `LCM001`:

```
LCM001 produto = params.getString("produto");
```

E garanta que `LCM001` seja uma subclasse de `Serializable` ou `Parcelable`.